# Understanding Aliasing and Tables, SQL

Tags: sql, select

I'm trying to an output table with each row representing posts in a thread and the columns subdividing the thread into question, answers, and comments.  I have the question and answer part down, now I need to add the comment section.

I'm trying to understand a solution I was given in order to play around with the code and add a third column for commenters. The pasted code creates two columns from one column of students' IDs. The first column is all the students who posted a question and the second is all the students who posted an answer in a given thread.

Table queried from:

```
thread_id    student_usrnm     post_type
1            iron_man          question
1            orient            answer
1            cyclops           comment
2            green_lantern     question
2            iron_man          answer
...          ....              .....
```

Output:

```
questioners     answerers      commenters
iron_man        orient         cyclops
green_lantern   iron_man
```

Here is the code that works and generates questioners and answerers:

```
 SELECT s1.author_id AS questioner,
(SELECT group_concat(DISTINCT author_id SEPARATOR " ") FROM students s2 WHERE s2.post_type = 'answer' AND   s2.thread_id = s1.thread_id)  AS answerers  
 FROM students s1
 WHERE s1.post_type = 'question';
```

Questions:

1. What is s1 and what is s2 and how do these work? Are they temporary tables or something?
2. How can I add a third column for commentators? This is my pathetic attempt to generate a third column:

   ```
   SELECT s1.author_id AS questioner,
     (SELECT group_concat(DISTINCT author_id SEPARATOR " ") 
     FROM students s2 WHERE s2.post_type = 'answer' AND s2.thread_id = s1.thread_id) AS answerers, 
     (SELECT group_concat(DISTINCT author_id SEPARATOR " ") FROM students s3 WHERE s3.post_type = 'comment' and s3.thread_id = s1.thread_id) AS commenters,    
     FROM students s1
     WHERE s1.post_type = 'question';
   ```

Comment: what kind of database are you using?

Comment: I'm doing all of this in sql pro

Comment: I think that the problem was actually just the comma after "commenters" in the penultimate line. Apologize that this was not a conceptual problem. Want to go ahead and claim the answer?

Comment: yeah your right, that extra comma would throw an error.  other than that the query looks good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aliasing allows you to rename both column and table names to anything of your choosing.   s1 and s2 both reference the same table, "students".  Here's a link that describes how to use aliasing  [SQL-Alias (w3schools)](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp).  See the "Alias Example for Tables"

Your friend used a subquery and selected from the same student table in order to get at people who answered the questions.  Your strategy for adding commentors is valid.  I created a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!8/16d62/6/0) to demonstrate that this works, play around with it to further customize your results.